# Portainer cannot access images in a registry behind a client TLS auth proxy for docker compose operations but can access it for individual image ops

Tags: docker, portainer

The setup here is that there's a GitLab registry that is behind a nginx setup which does client TLS verification. This *works* with the `docker` CLI commands and with Portainer commands which deal with individual images / containers. Client certs are placed in `/etc/docker/certs.d/reponame...`.

For example, I can pull individual images in Portainer, I can rebuild a container based on an image, with the "pull image" option enabled, and it just works.

But any operation which deals with the "docker compose" part of Portainer fails with HTTP 401. It's like that part of Portainer doesn't call into regular `docker` CLI or it just fails to read those certs.

Has anyone encountered this before, and are there any workarounds?